# How do I affect all the classes on javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, for-loop, element, getelementsbyclassname

Here is my sample code for HTML And CSS

```
body{
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

.box{
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
  position:relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.bold{
  font-weight: bold;
}
.table{
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}




</style>
```

```
<p class="bold">Your Time: <span id="time">0.000</span>s</p>

<table id="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="table"><div class="box"></div></td>
      <td class="table"><div class="box"></div></td>
      <td class="table"><div class="box"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table"><div class="box"></div></td>
      <td class="table"><div class="box"></div></td>
      <td class="table"><div class="box"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table"><div class="box"></div></td>
      <td class="table"><div class="box"></div></td>
      <td class="table"><div class="box"></div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">


function getRandomColor() {
     var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
     var color = '#';
     for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
 }


var clickedTime; var createdTime; var reactionTime;


function makeBox(){

    createdTime=Date.now();

    var time = Math.random();

    time = 5000*time;

    var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

    setTimeout(function(){

      if(Math.random()>0.5){


        for (var i=0;i<box.length; i++) {
              box[i].style.borderRadius="100px";

        }else{

          for (var i=0;i<box.length; i++) {
              box[i].style.borderRadius="0";
        }

        for (var i=0;i<box.length; i++) {
              box[i].style.backgroundColor=getRandomColor();

        for (var i=0;i<box.length; i++) {
              box[i].style.display="block";

        createdTime=Date.now();
    }, time);
}

       for (var i=0;i<box.length; i++) {
              box[i].onclick=function(){

        clickedTime=Date.now();

        reactionTime=(clickedTime-createdTime)/1000;

        document.getElementById('time')[0].innerHTML=reactionTime;

        this.style.display="none";

        makeBox();
   }

   makeBox();

</script>
```

My goal here is to display different shapes in 9 boxes all together at once and I'm starting out first to display a shape in all the boxes but when I use this code, nothing shows up. Also, I've checked for codes about getting elements about classes, it seems to be a bit more than getting ids. And I've tried using for loops to be able to access all the elements but I don't know why it doesnt work. :/

Comment: is the shape supposed to be the same in all the boxes?

Comment: It's easier if you use the "new" querySelector()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: Did you make sure that the DOM was loaded before looking up the elements?

Comment: @Sebastian Nette: I wasn't planning on using DOM, but is it required so it can work?

Comment: @ninja—changing from *document.getElementsByClassName('box')* to *document.querySelectorAll('.box')* saves precisely 5 characters. Other than that, how is it "easier"?

Comment: @RonnAtienzaSicuan: You *are* using the DOM already, otherwise you couldn't manipulate your page at all :-)

Comment: Also dude code contains lots of errors. Consider fixing errors before you post them here.

Comment: @RonnAtienzaSicuan: DOM refers to the HTML node tree. Just make sure to run your script after the elements have been added on the page. Also you forgot to add some closing brackets after your for loops and after the else case.

Comment: @RobG I have a qustion, Is it true that the first letter of the class name should be capitalized ? *(in php)*  Tnx

Answer (score 0):

There were few syntax errors, missing `}`:

```js
var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

setTimeout(function() {

  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {

    for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
      box[i].style.borderRadius = "100px";
    }

  } else {

    for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
      box[i].style.borderRadius = "0";
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
      box[i].style.backgroundColor = 'orange'; // for test purpose replaced with `getRandomColor()`
    } //<-- missing
    for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
      box[i].style.display = "block";
    } //<-- missing
    createdTime = Date.now();
  } //<-- missing
}, 100); //<-- for test purpose replaced with `time`
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 3px 4px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="table">
        <div class="box"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="table">
        <div class="box"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="table">
        <div class="box"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table">
        <div class="box"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="table">
        <div class="box"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="table">
        <div class="box"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table">
        <div class="box"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="table">
        <div class="box"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="table">
        <div class="box"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>`
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you applied any css styles to the box class? If not, the width and height will be 0 which is why you won't see anything.

Try adding this in the `<head>` of your html:

```
<style>
.box
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script seems to work quite fine for me,

If you just ensure to give a width and height to your .box elements:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FloSchieldBobby/1gb0ae9q/

```js
var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

var getRandomColor = function () {
    return 'rgb(' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ', ' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ', ' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ')';
};

setTimeout(function(){
    
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        
        for (var i=0;i<box.length; i++) {
            box[i].style.borderRadius="100px";
        }
        
    } else {
        for (var i=0;i<box.length; i++) {
            box[i].style.borderRadius="0";
        }
    }
    
    for (var i=0;i<box.length; i++) {
        box[i].style.backgroundColor=getRandomColor();
        box[i].style.display="block";
    }
    
    createdTime = Date.now();
}, 100);
```

```css
#table {
    width: 100%;
}

#table .box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="table"><div class="box"></div></td>
            <td class="table"><div class="box"></div></td>
            <td class="table"><div class="box"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="table"><div class="box"></div></td>
            <td class="table"><div class="box"></div></td>
            <td class="table"><div class="box"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="table"><div class="box"></div></td>
            <td class="table"><div class="box"></div></td>
            <td class="table"><div class="box"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
#table {
    width: 100%;
}

#table .box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you confused setTimout and Set Interval. Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/arunzo/j4uqLenx/

```
  var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

 function getRandomColor() {
     var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
     var color = '#';
     for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
         color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
     }
     return color;
 }

 setInterval(function () {
     console.log("Tick");
     if (Math.random() > 0.5) {

         for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
             box[i].style.borderRadius = "100px";
         }

     } else {

         for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
             box[i].style.borderRadius = "0";
         }

         for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
             box[i].style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
         }

         for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
             box[i].style.display = "block";
         }


     }
 }, 1000);
```